# Does the T-34 tank engine use different strokes in the banks of the pistons?

Tags: tanks

It's relatively well documented the T-34 tank uses a V arrangement engine in all variants.

I found this CIA document that was declassified:

https://www.cia.gov/library/readingroom/docs/CIA-RDP82-00457R008300010007-6.pdf

It is difficult to read but it states

```
Piston Stroke 180mm left block
186.7mm right block
```

Does the engine of the T-34 have different stroke between the left and right bank? So the pistons of one bank would have less displacement than the other one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The t-34 tank used the Kharkiv model v-2 engine, which apparently did indeed have different strokes for the cylinder banks, at least according to Wikipedia

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kharkiv_model_V-2

> Displacement 38.8 L (2,367.7 cu in), bore 150 mm (5.9 in), stroke 180 mm (7.1 in) left cylinder group and 186 mm (7.3 in) right cylinder group, torque 220 kgf⋅m (2,157.5 N⋅m; 1,591.3 lbf⋅ft).

According to some forum posts on the world of tracks forums

> Same thing goes with many soviet build engines, for example T-54/55 have basically the same engine. That odd stroke is because the pistons are linked to the central crank shaft by wrist connecting rods, which means that only six rods are directly connected to the crank shaft. This special design also results in a slightly lower stroke in both sides of the engine

Comment: It seems inappropriate to quote Wikipedia in answer to a query driven by a source  upstream of Wikipedia. In a case like this, I believe a more primary source is required, as for all we know Wiki is just referencing the original CIA document. At least, note whether the sources referenced in Wikipedia are up- or down-stream of the original CIA source.

Answer (score 3):

Page 5 of "Report on Russian C.I. Tank Engine, Type V2 from T-34 Crusier Tank" from the Military College of Science in 1944 [Report on Russian-C-I Tank Engine Type V2 from T-34 Cruiser Tank](https://www.scribd.com/document/241819955/Report-on-Russian-C-I-Tank-Engine-Type-V2-from-T-34-Cruiser-Tank) has a cross section diagram of the engine. This shows one bank of cylinders has conventional connecting rods and the other has "wrist" connection rods. The report also states that the bank with conventional rods has a shorter stroke, and lower capacity, than the other bank.

Comment: Funny that the paper calls the T-34 a "Cruiser Tank", a classification used by the British, not the Russians.

Comment: @DevSolar Well, the report was written by the British Military College of Science School of Tank Technology at Chertsey.